# php - reload current page after dropdown onchange action

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown element in my header file. The dropdown contains 2 currencies that I'd like users on my site to choose from:

```
<div class = "currencyswitcher">
 <span class = "currencylabel"><strong>Currency Switcher</strong> </span>
<form method="post" id="switchcurrency" name = "switchcurrency">
    <select name = "currency" id = "currency" >
        <option value = "USD"> USD </option>
        <option value = "KES"> KES </option>
    </select>

</form>
</div>
```

This is processed by an ajax script which posts the selected element to another file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "<?php echo file2.php;?>";
    $('#currency').change( function() {
       $.ajax({ 
           data: $('#switchcurrency').serialize(), 
           type: "POST",
           url: url, 
           success: function(response) { 
               alert(response);

           }
       });
    });  

}); 
</script>
```

now, in my file2.php I want to pass the value from my dropdown and append it to the url of the page i'm on i.e. if i'm on the page sitename.php/page1 then after selecting from the drop down, the page refreshes to sitename.php/page1?currency=USD and if i were on sitename.php/page2, upon selection, page refreshes to sitename.php/page2?currency=KES and so forth...

this is my file2.php(the file ajax is posting to)

```
if(isset($_POST["currency"]))
{
    $key = key($_POST);
    $value = $_POST["currency"];

    $params = array_merge($_GET, array($key => $value));
    $new_query_string = http_build_query($params);

    $url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"http://":"https://") . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "?" . $new_query_string;
    var_dump($url);
}
```

From the above my dump returns the url of my header page i.e

```
var_dump($url); = mysiteurl/header.php?currency=USD
```

So here's my question: with my dropdown in the header(therefore called on all the pages in my site), how do I enforce it such that upon selecting an option, the current page I'm on refreshes having the selected option appended to the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.done` callback in your ajax to handle changing the `window.location.href` property (of which you can just append your currency parameter key/value pair):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "<?php echo file2.php;?>";
    $('#currency').change( function() {
       $.ajax({ 
           data: $('#currency').serialize(), 
           type: "POST",
           url: url, 
           success: function(response) { 
               alert(response);
           }
       }).done(function() {
           window.location.href = window.location.href + "?currency="+$('#switchcurrency').val();
       });;
    });  
});
```

**Further reading:**

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Excellent this works though there's a slight miss here: window.location.href = window.location.href + "?currency="+$('#switchcurrency').val(); should be: window.location.href = window.location.href + "?currency="+$('#currency').val();

Comment: One more tiny thing I may have missed out, what happens when I'm on a page like this: mysiteurl.php/?someparameter. if I select from dropdown, i'll get this: mysiteurl.php/?someparameter?currency=USD instead of mysiteurl.php/?someparameter&currency=USD. any tip on this bit?

Comment: fixed the id of the select in the code.  For the other issue you can use the `window.location` objects properties (linked above) to determine if there are GET parameters already in the url... so you'll want to make that determination and add a condition to handle how you append your currency parameter (with ? or &)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "<?php echo file2.php;?>";
    $('#currency').change( function() {
       $.ajax({ 
           data: $('#switchcurrency').serialize(), 
           type: "POST",
           url: url, 
           success: function(response) { 
                 //Choose one!!

               // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
                  window.location.replace(response);

              // similar behavior as clicking on a link
                 window.location.href = response;

           }
       });
    });  

}); 
</script>



 if(isset($_POST["currency"]))
{
    $key = key($_POST);
    $value = $_POST["currency"];

    $params = array_merge($_GET, array($key => $value));
    $new_query_string = http_build_query($params);

    $url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"http://":"https://") . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "?" . $new_query_string;
    exit($url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this redirects me to the header page as I had stated in my question